# Выбрать имена согласно id

Tags: запрос, select, mysql

Всем привет! Помогите с запросом. Есть 2 таблицы

1.Список пользователей

```
user_id
name
```

2.Список товаров

```
id
user_1 (user_id тот кто продает)
user_2 (user_id тот кто покупает)
```

Мне нужно выбрать строки из таблицы 2 с именами (name) согласно user_id. Помогите разобраться!

Comment: [Выборка из двух таблиц в MySQL. Оператор JOIN.](http://webextends.net/articles/9-mysql/8-mysql-join.html)

Comment: Используйте 2 LEFT JOIN

Comment: такой лепет должны знать, стыдно не знать.

Comment: @IntegralAL стыдно на so-подобном сайте указывать кому-то на недостатки.

Comment: @Etki, поверьте мне тоже кто что критикует, это нормально. Я ни жалуюсь на то что обвиняют иногда в том что я чего-то не знаю или не умею. Критика просто стимулирует иногда на больший прогресс, а иногда ломает.

Comment: @IntegralAL угу, у меня по ночам под окнами тоже "критика"